# How to get FireMonkey Framework on RAD Studio XE7

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, c++builder-xe7

I have RAD Studio XE7 installed on my computer and i have everything like VCL Forms for Delphi, C++.etc but how do i manage to get FireMonkey HD and 3D application frameworks for Delphi and C++ Builder both in RAD Studio XE7.Do I have to download it or it is already in RAD Studio XE7 and I have to follow some steps to get FireMonkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FireMonkey is pre-installed as part of the IDE.  You do not need to do anything extra to get it.

In earlier versions, there were separate `FireMonkey Desktop Application` (which had HD and 3D options) and `FireMonkey Mobile Application` projects.  They no longer exist as separate projects in XE7.  They have been merged together into a single `Multi-Device Application` project.

When you create a new `Multi-Device Application` project, the dialog that appears is the same as the old `FireMonkey Mobile Application` project, where one of the options is `3D Application`.

Comment: I used 3D Application but i can't add anything to it(not even 3D shapes) and when I run it, it gives me error,something like access of violation.Do you know how I can ignore it

Comment: What actually happens when you try to "add anything to it"? What are you adding exactly?  BTW, an Access Violation means invalid memory is being accessed. You don't really want to ignore that.  Is it happening in the IDE itself, or when you run your app?

Comment: So what could I add in the 3D application.I have tried to add 3D shapes but it was useless

Comment: But **why** is it useless? What is actually happening when you try?